# Which rear wheel axle does my “Citizen Gotham 7” folding bike use?

Tags: wheels, axle

[image]

Which rear wheel axle does my “Citizen Gotham 7” folding bike use?[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like standard 10mm bolt on axle.

Comment: This got flagged so probably needs some more detail. not sure what exactly because the question was also brief

Comment: I'm sure someone will eventually write a long essay on axle types. At that point I'm fine if someone deletes this.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Citizens' web site photos show a standard quick release on the Citizen 7. The three speed internally geared models use a bolt on axle.

Comment: Newer photos show a single-speed with a solid rear axle and traditional wheel nuts.  Perhaps OP's bike had a different wheel fitted at some point?